# Writing function to take object of key/value pairs and a function, and returning an array of values where key matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to create a javascript function which takes in an object of key/value pairs and
a filter function that accepts one argument and returns a Boolean.  The function should return an array containing the *values* from the object for which filter(*key*) is true.

So I would have a function:

```
function filterValuesByKeys(obj, filter){
//returns array
}
```

What I'm mostly stuck on is looping through the object based on the keys, and adding the value to an array if the key matched/satisfied the argument.  I can print all of the keys, but I don't know how to get each key individually in a loop.

Comment: `for (var k in obj) { console.log(k); }`

Comment: `Object.values(obj).filter(filter)`?

Comment: `Object.values` is experimental (part of ES7 proposal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). That will definitely be helpful for this kind of thing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping through a JavaScript object, you want to be careful about what you're trying to accomplish. Using `for (var key in obj)` will go through all the keys, but also any keys in the object's prototype chain.

One approach to get only the object's "own" properties is using for/in, but then checking

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Another option with more traditional looping is to use `Object.keys(obj)` to get the own keys of `obj`. You can then do a regular loop through that array or even use `forEach` on it.

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(function(key) {
    // do stuff 
});
```

There are some other neat ways using native functional Array methods, like `reduce`. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function customFilter(v) {
  return (v.indexOf('c') === 0);
}

function filterValuesByKeys(obj, filter) {
  var ary = [],
      keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(function(k) {
    if (filter(k)) {
      ary.push(obj[k]);
    }
  })
  return ary;
}

var person = {
  name: 'George',
  age: 50,
  address: '1 center st',
  city: 'some city',
  state: 'some state',
  country: 'USA'
};

var result = filterValuesByKeys(person, customFilter);

console.log(result);
```